# How do I map an operator over a list of functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, expression-manipulation

Long-time programmer, but new to Mathematica (and for that matter, math). I'm trying to do something that feels pretty basic to me, but that for the life of me, I can't make work:

I want to, having input an array of *functions*, map them through a higher-order function, resulting in a different array of functions. Something like, very vaguely, this:

```
D /@ {Sin, Cos, Tan}  (*→ {Cos[x], -Sin[x], Sec[x]^2} *)
```

(I already understand that I'm using the wrong words to ask this question — but I'm not yet too familiar with Mathematica's terms for things I'd have considered “basic programming things”, as evidenced by the fact that I seem unable to drag a straight answer to this question out of Google and/or Mathematica's documentation. )

---

Pursuant to avoiding an [X/Y question](http://xyproblem.info), here's my current little goal (although doing this in such an over-complicated way is obv. just a learning-Mathematica-programming exercise):

> Create a table of the first and second derivatives for each of the trigonometric, inverse-trigonometric, and hyperbolic functions: `Sin[x]` → `Cos[x]` → `-Sin[x]`, so on, so forth, to then copy into a LaTeX document.

I know I can complete the last bit of that with `// TableForm`, but the first part is stumping me, short of manually typing out `{{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x], ...}, {D[Sin[x], x], D[Cos[x], x], D[Tan[x], x], ...}, {...}, {...}}`

Comment: You want `Derivative[]` for this: `Derivative[1] /@ {Sin, Cos, Tan}`. If pure functions still make you uncomfortable: `Through[(Derivative[1] /@ {Sin, Cos, Tan})[x]]`.

Comment: Actually `D` can do it too. See my answer below.

Comment: For copying to a LaTex document, you can use `TeXForm[Table[...]]` which will simplify the process a little. Also, if you want to _evaluate_ the functions in the table, one easy way is to define the table as a function: `funderivs[x_] = Table[D[...]]`. Another way would be to use @J.M.'s pure functions. It would depend on how you want to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
funcs = {Sin, ArcSin, Cos, ArcCos, Tan, ArcTan};
Table[D[#[x] &, {x, n}] /@ funcs, {n, 0, 2}] // Transpose // TableForm
```

[image: table]

Comment: Actually, just the `D[ #[x], x] &` is precisely what I was looking for — even though I didn't know. Thank you!